# Referencing a .dll in another folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lib

Say I have an `A.lib` file that refers to two other dlls : `A1.dll` and `A2.dll`.

In addition I have another `B.lib` file that calls `A.lib`.

If I want to run an `test.exe` which calls `B.lib`; for all the functions to be found, currently, I must put `A.lib`, `A1.dll`, `A2.dll` and `B.lib` in the same folder as `test.exe`.

Is there a way to compile the solution (I am looking for a Visual Studio setting) such that:

- `test.exe`, `A.lib`, `B.lib` is in folder A
- `A1.dll` and `A2.dll` is in folder B, and somehow `A.lib` is able to reference this folder when `test.exe` is running?

Comment: Visual C++ compiles to native code. At runtime, it's Windows which loads the DLL. You need to check Windows documentation. The .lib isn't used at run time.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you just need to make sure the project can find the .lib files and header files it needs. I suggest you could refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/adding-references-in-visual-cpp-projects?view=vs-2019#dynamic-link-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Set your project to use [Delay Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=vs-2019) for the DLLs, then your code can call [`SetDllDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw) or [`AddDllDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory) at runtime before doing anything that needs to use the DLLs.